# Office web add-in in JS and login with SSAL : interaction_in_progress after login

Tags: authentication, add-in, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to get an access token from Microsoft to connect to Graph API, by using a client that is a web add-in in Word 365 desktop (pure JS, not made with Angular or Node).

To authenticate, this is the code I'm using:

```
window.Office.onReady(() => {
    initMsalInstance();
});

function initMsalInstance() {
    myMSALObj =  new msal.PublicClientApplication({
        auth: {
            clientId: "...",
            authority: "...",
            redirectUri: "",
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
            storeAuthStateInCookie: true
        }
    });

    myMSALObj.handleRedirectPromise()
        .then((response) => {
            if (response) {
                console.log(response);
            } else {
                console.log('noresp');
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        });
}

function signIn() {
    myMSALObj.loginRedirect({
        scopes: ['user.read', 'files.read.all']
    });
}
```

I just have a button that calls the "signIn()" method, then it opens Chrome, I'm loggin in, and I'm redirected to the page I selected.

Unfortunately, in the add-in, nothing happens, my handleRedirectPromise() doesn't seem to get called, so I don't have the response and the token.

If I'm trying to click on "sign in" again, then this is the error I get:

> interaction_in_progress: Interaction is currently in progress. Please ensure that this interaction has been completed before calling an interactive API.  For more visit: aka.ms/msaljs/browser-errors.

What can I do to complete the process and get my token into my Office 365 Word Web add-in?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because of this piece of code:

```
msalInstance.loginRedirect(loginRequest);
```

This code looks into the session storage for the key  `MSAL.[clientId].interaction.status` and other temp values required for redirection process.
If such value exist and it's value equals the 'interaction_in_progress' then error will be thrown.

This is the known issue in [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2941).

Follow these steps to resolve this issue.

Account selection logic is app dependent and adjust as needed for different use cases. Set active account on page load.

```
const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
if (accounts.length > 0) {
msalInstance.setActiveAccount(accounts[0]);
}



msalInstance.addEventCallback((event) => {

if (event.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS && event.payload.account) {
const account = event.payload.account;
msalInstance.setActiveAccount(account);
}
}, error=>{
console.log('error', error);
});
console.log('get active account', msalInstance.getActiveAccount());
```

// handle auth redirect/do all initial setup for MSAL

```
msalInstance.handleRedirectPromise().then(authResult=>{
```

// Check if user signed in

```
const account = msalInstance.getActiveAccount();
if(!account){
```

// redirect anonymous user to login page

```
msalInstance.loginRedirect();
}
}).catch(err=>{
```

// TODO: Handle errors

```
console.log(err);
});
```